# Access Select Query recordset not Updateable

Tags: ms-access

I have a Access 2010 Form that is linked to Sql Server and I am using a select query that works correctly until I add an Inner Join and then the field becomes unable to update (Recordset is not Updateable) This is the query I am using but cant check the field Yes(this is a checkbox), if I remove the inner join it works. column nm has can have more than one name in it so to get the latest name I am using the inner join with the max to give me the latest name otherwise it will show both names in the nm column.

```
SELECT tblA.Reference
 TblA.Yes,
 TblA.Nm,
 TblA.PKID
FROM TblA 

INNER JOIN (
SELECT 
Reference,
max(PKID) AS TRANID 
FROM TblA 
GROUP BY Reference)  AS TblB ON TblA.Reference = TblB.Reference AND 
TblA.PKID = TblB.TRANID)

WHERE TblA.Reference Like "*" & [forms]![NewPayments]![Combo1] & "*" AND 
TblA.Nm Like "*" & [forms]![NewPayments]![ClientName] & "*" AND 
TblA.Account Like "*" & [forms]![NewPayments]![ACN] & "*" AND 
TblA.Query Is Null ;
```

Comment: I have read a few things on this but after hours of trying to get my result I am still unable, does this mean what I am trying to do is not possible? Thanks

Comment: Well... you haven't actually told us what you want to do. We can't magically make this query updateable, no. But you aren't selecting anything from TblB, so I don't know why you have it there.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining, column nm has can have more than one name in it so to get the latest name I am using the inner join with the max to give me the latest name otherwise it will show both names in the nm column.

Comment: Consider editing the question to include that. That would make it not be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use aggregates only to select specific entries, you can use `EXISTS` instead of `INNER JOIN` to keep the query updateable.

```
SELECT tblA.Reference
 TblA.Yes,
 TblA.Nm,
 TblA.PKID
FROM TblA 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TblA As TblB
    WHERE TblA.Reference = TblB.Reference
    HAVING TblA.PKID = max(TblB.PKID)
) AND TblA.Reference Like "*" & [forms]![NewPayments]![Combo1] & "*" AND 
TblA.Nm Like "*" & [forms]![NewPayments]![ClientName] & "*" AND 
TblA.Account Like "*" & [forms]![NewPayments]![ACN] & "*" AND 
TblA.Query Is Null ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! and sorry again for not being clear with my question!